# Redactor plugin won't appear thought the plugin JavaScript is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

Code below:

```
jQuery('#pagetext').redactor({
    "imageUpload":"/admin/redactor/uploaddir=pages",
    "fileUpload":"/admin/redactor/upload?dir=pages",
    "minHeight":400,
    "plugins"["fontcolor","fontsize"],
    "imageUploadErrorCallback":function(json{alert(json.error);},
    "fileUploadErrorCallback":function(json{alert(json.error);},
});
```

And jQuery, Redactor and all the plugins have loaded before this code.
but in the editor there's not a color button to change the color?
what's the problem here?

Comment: You forgot a `:` on the "plugins" line... Is that the issue?

Comment: @LuudJacobs no, not that problem.I forgot to add the js file of the plugins. so it's not working.